# IbPy download historical price data

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

How can i download historical price data from interactive brokers using IbPy and python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checked in my python script for daily futures data from Interactive Brokers. Maybe it will be useful for you:

https://github.com/busygin/ib_data_loader

Comment: Nice! I will take a look!