# How to get historical data for expired futures contracts in IbPy?

Tags: futures, interactive-brokers

Does anyone know how to request historical data for futures contracts that have already expired in IbPy?
There are plenty of examples for requesting historical data for [example this post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17516/ibpy-download-historical-price-data), however these fail if you put in a contract expiration date that is in the past.

Answer (score 6):

After some research and [reading the source](https://github.com/blampe/IbPy/blob/master/ib/ext/Contract.py), I found there is a field in the Contract class called: m_includeExpired.  Set this to True and you can get data for expired contracts.

Comment: How far back does this go? The docs on [Unavailable Historical Data](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/historical_limitations.html) say "Expired futures data older than two years counting from the future's expiration date."

Comment: @Peter It's been a while since it was posted. It doesn't seem to work for me. Any new thought?